# How to import a module from the root dir having another with same name in a descendent package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm using python 2.7.10.

I understand that there is many questions related to this. I'm starting this question because none of answers I found in StackOverflow answers my doubts. My goal here is to clarify my understanding about the Python import machinery with the help of the community.

I have a project with a structure like this:

```
./
./config.py
./modules
./modules/__init__.py
./modules/config.py
```

**config.py**

```
VALUE = 1
```

**modules/config.py**

```
import config
print(config.VALUE)
```

In this module, I want to get the VALUE constant from the module in the root dir and print it. When I run the config in modules package I get the following error:

```
$ python modules/config.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modules/config.py", line 1, in <module>
    import config
  File "/test/modules/config.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(config.VALUE)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VALUE'
```

I understand that the **import config** statement imports the module in the current directory instead the one in the root dir. So I need to add a *kind of hack* to allow it import the module in the root dir:

**modules/config.py**

```
def import_from_root(name):
    import os
    import imp
    root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__name__))
    root_module = os.path.join(root_path, '{}.py'.format(name))
    return imp.load_source('root_'.format(name), root_module)

print(import_from_root('config').VALUE)
```

Now it works:

```
$ python modules/config.py
1
```

But I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this. So, I have the following questions:

1. Is there a more pythonic way to solve this?
2. To move to Python 3.x will improve this?

Please, consider that I don't want to change the directory structure or the names of the modules.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). Basically you might want to temporarily modify `sys.path`

Comment: @Alik to change `sys.path` is a *kind of hack*. I think that changing sys.path is a bad practice.

Comment: other ways are more uglier and hacky, but you didn't clarify what exactly you wanted to see in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you'd rather change your current working directory than your sys path:

```
from os import chdir
chdir('/')
import config
```

this might be better if you have other resources in root. Both this and the above solution are more parsimonious and pythonic than your current solution.

Comment: by changing the current directory will work for this specific case, but it can cause unpredictable side effects if there is other modules running the import machinery (think in a multi thread environment).